How to install speech recognition module for Python 2.7?
I am trying to install the following module https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition from PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) for my installed Python 2.7 using the command:
py -2.7 -m pip install SpeechRecognition==3.8.1

But the error I get is:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol'),)) - skipping

How to solve this and eventually install The SpeechRecognition v3.8.1 which is compatible with Python 2.7?

Is there a particular reason you want to use python 2.7? Looking at the requirements of the library it states "To use all of the functionality of the library, you should have:    Python 3.8+ (required)"  and a bit below "The first software requirement is Python 3.8+. This is required to use the library." So it's very unlikely it will work on python 2.7

v3.8.1 was released at the time of Python 2, why wouldn't it work?

Ok my fault. v3.8.1 should work on python 2.7 (last comment was about v3.10.4)  https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/3.8.1/  but your error doesn't seem to be related to library compatibility, just being unable to fetch from an url dues to a ssl certificate on pypi.org
